# Initial value of multiple variables dataframe for time dilation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time

Dataframe:

| product1 | product2 | product3 | product4 | product5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| straws | orange | melon | chair | bread |
| melon | milk | book | coffee | cake |
| bread | melon | coffe | chair | book |

| CountProduct1 | CountProduct2 | CountProduct3 | Countproduct4 | Countproduct5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

| RatioProduct1 | RatioProduct2 | RatioProduct3 | Ratioproduct4 | Ratioproduct5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.28 | 0.54 | 0.33 | 0.35 | 0.11 |
| 0.67 | 0.25 | 0.13 | 0.11 | 0.59 |
| 2.5 | 1.69 | 1.9 | 2.5 | 1.52 |

I want to create five others columns that keep my initial ratio of each item along the dataframe.

Output:

| InitialRatio1 | InitialRatio2 | InitialRatio3 | InitialRatio4 | InitialRatio5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.28 | 0.54 | 0.33 | 0.35 | 0.11 |
| 0.33 | 0.25 | 0.13 | 0.31 | 0.59 |
| 0.11 | 0.33 | 0.31 | 0.35 | 0.13 |

Comment: the ratio is taken by first occurence (already given). The count column represent the occurence of the product in time. So has +1 occurence, the ratio of the product grow in time. So I need columns that keep the ratio of first occurrence  (count=1) . The pseudo code would be something like for items in products if columns count==1 , product=ratio. But it should keep that initial ratio along the df. I have over 1500 items  so create dictionnary is really to big. And dataframe is huge.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that we only change the first 'melon'? It is not clear if you have a third, fourth, etc.

Comment: No. Melon have an initial rate of 0.33 in the first row, in the third row melon appear a second time with a ratio of 0.66. On the output i write 0.33 on the third row for melon wich is the initial rate. All I want is columns with initial for each products.

Comment: @BrySab to be honest mate this is one of the most confusing questions I've come across.  The data is represented strangely (I'd take a look at "tidy data" if I were you), seems to lack any physical context to help it make sense, and the probem is not well explained.  You probably need to have a think if this is the best way to pose it.

Comment: I really don't know what to say. It just so simple for me. The only thing I need is columns that map initial ratio of products along the df. I gonna try to find another way.

Comment: The initial ratio is where every rows of columns count ==1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code again. Do you have an error in product3 = coffe and product4 = coffee? Fixed coffe to coffee. As a result, 0.31 should not be.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # print everything rows
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  # print everything columns

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'product1':['straws', 'melon', 'bread'],
    'product2':['orange', 'milk', 'melon'],
    'product3':['melon', 'book', 'coffee'],
    'product4':['chair', 'coffee', 'chair'],
    'product5':['bread', 'cake', 'book'],
    'time':[1,2,3],
    'Count1':[1,2,2],
    'Count2':[1,1,3],
    'Count3':[1,1,2],
    'Count4':[1,1,2],
    'Count5':[1,1,2],
    'ratio1':[0.28, 0.67, 2.5],
    'ratio2':[0.54, 0.25, 1.69],
    'ratio3':[0.33, 0.13, 1.9],
    'ratio4':[0.35, 0.11, 2.5],
    'ratio5':[0.11, 0.59, 1.52],

})

print(df)

product = df[['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5']].stack().reset_index()
count = df[['Count1',  'Count2',  'Count3', 'Count4',  'Count5']].stack().reset_index()
ratio = df[['ratio1',  'ratio2',  'ratio3',  'ratio4',  'ratio5']].stack().reset_index()
print(ratio)


arr = pd.unique(product[0])
aaa = [i for i in range(len(arr)) if product[product[0] == arr[i]].count()[0] > 1]
for i in aaa:
    prod_ind = product[product[0] == arr[i]].index
    val_ratio = ratio.loc[prod_ind[0], 0]
    ratio.loc[prod_ind, 0] = val_ratio

print(ratio.pivot_table(index='level_0', columns='level_1', values=[0]))
```

Output:

```
level_1 ratio1 ratio2 ratio3 ratio4 ratio5
level_0                                   
0         0.28   0.54   0.33   0.35   0.11
1         0.33   0.25   0.13   0.11   0.59
2         0.11   0.33   0.11   0.35   0.13
```

To work with data, they need to be turned into one column using stack().reset_index(). Create a list of unique products **arr**. Further in the list **aaa** I get indexes of **arr**, which are more than one.

```
prod_ind = product[product[0] == arr[i]].index
```

In a loop, I get indexes of products that are more than one.

```
val_ratio = ratio.loc[prod_ind[0], 0]
```

Get the first value of the product.

```
ratio.loc[prod_ind, 0] = val_ratio
```

Set this value for all products.
To access the values, explicit **loc** indexing is used, where the row indices are in square brackets on the left, and the names of the columns on the right. Read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc).

In [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) I create back the table.
To insert the processed data into the original dataframe, simply use the following:

```
table = ratio.pivot_table(index='level_0', columns='level_1', values=[0])
df[['ratio1',  'ratio2',  'ratio3',  'ratio4',  'ratio5']] = table
print(df)
```

Comment: No it doesn't work on my df.  Some values on the first column work at the begining of the dataframe but the rest till the end doesn't have a sense. I try to be intuitive on your code and replace count ['value'] to 1 but it doesnt work either.

Comment: Then explain in more detail, provide more data to make it clear. Step by step, using the example of a melon, describe what you need. I assume that more data needs to be shown and naturally the expected result from them. On the data that you provided, it works. And something tells me that I can’t help you, because you yourself don’t fully know what you want. It's hard to find a black cat in a dark room, especially if it's not there. I used pd.melt to put all the data into one column so I can work with it iteratively. Then I converted the finished result back into a table (ratio.pivot)

Comment: In general, I'm waiting for a specific explanation (I made a screen from the page).

Comment: I saw it man and yes thanks for your help cant imagine how happy and sad I'm at the same time, I know exactly what I want it just I really don't know our to explain better. Give me a moment a will try to put it on table for better understanding. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: BTW what you write as an output is exactly the result. But on my long df on colab when I look at the end it gave me different results.

Comment: Hi  inquirer, i change the publication with tables and simplify it. Now almost every products have 2 occurences and melon has 3. Ratio grow in time in each occurence but there's no calcs between that grow and occurence. Ratio is a trend of product per time T,and it starts with the initial value wich is 0.33 for melon. Tell me if i explain it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after code to create the `init_rateX` columns then the following will work

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.divide(
        df[["ratio1", "ratio2", "ratio3", "ratio4", "ratio5"]].to_numpy(),
        df[["Count1", "Count2", "Count3", "Count4", "Count5"]].to_numpy(),
    ),
    columns=["init_rate1", "init_rate2", "init_rate3", "init_rate4", "init_rate5"],
)
```

which gives

```
   init_rate1  init_rate2  init_rate3  init_rate4  init_rate5
0        0.28        0.25        0.33        0.57       0.835
1        0.33        0.13        0.97        0.65       0.760
2        0.54        0.11        0.45        0.95       1.160
3        0.35        0.59        0.34        1.25       1.650
```

However it does not agree with your calcs for `init_rate4` or `init_rate5` so some clarification might be needed.

Comment: HI Riley glad to see you in here. No it's more tricky than that in fact. All items start with an initial ratio. Ex: 'melon' ==0.33 on his first count (count1=1), on his second occurence his ratio is 0.66 (count=2). What i need is for every items where count=1 ratio=intial_ratio.

Comment: Btw i've realise there is a mistake on starws for the count, my bad.

Comment: the ratio does not grow by multipliying the initial rate by count so you cannot divide to get your initial rate. It works  like this math ODE x(t)= lambda t + C where C is x1 (our initial rate).